# Finding a Integer among set of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
11.117643101389094
14.439701045971955
1.0
4.459431618637297
7.794415866350106
11.117643101389094
1.0
4.459431618637297
7.794415866350106
```

How can I find the `float` with `0` fraction value in the above set of numbers i.e `1.0` which is termed as a float when I use `isinstance(h,int)`. where `h` is variable output containing these values.

Comment: what is your expected output.?

Comment: Do you want to consider 1.0 as a Integer?

Comment: I think  he wants to find out float with 0 fraction value

Answer (score 5):

If you want list as output you can use `list-comprehension` with [`is_integer`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html) :

```
ints = [i for i in k if i.is_integer()]
print(ints)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you iterate over these numbers, you can use

```
(i).is_integer()
```

which will return True when i is 1.0.

Comment: Why parentheses around `i`, though?

Comment: Because without those you are only referencing the method object. With them you tell Python you wanted to call the method.

Comment: That's the second set of parentheses, after `is_integer`. I'm asking about the first set, surrounding `i`.

Comment: They're not needed in this case, but when you replace i with a number, it will be. Its a bit subjective and it comes down to style and preference.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with [`is_digit()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html):

```
s = [11.117643101389094, 14.439701045971955, 1.0, 4.459431618637297, 7.794415866350106, 11.117643101389094, 1.0, 4.459431618637297, 7.794415866350106]

print(list(filter(lambda x: x.is_integer(), s)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[1.0, 1.0]
```